Reduce bandwidth consumption on firebase storage - Flutter
I'm making an app that provides images to download and view, currently there are only 50 people and bandwidth consumption is already high and I don't want to go beyond Firebase's Spark plan, would there be a way to improve this consumption and make it lower, or even another solution to save and search these images?
What would be a good option besides storage?
I tried caching the images on the device itself, and I thought about saving the URL of the images in Firestore, but I don't know if that would work.


Currently there are only 50 people and bandwidth consumption is already high and I don't want to go beyond Firebase's Spark plan.

This is happening most likely because you have stored large files in the Storage. Downloading large files means increased bandwidth consumption and higher bills.

Would there be a way to improve this consumption and make it lower, or even another solution to save and search these images?

When it comes to images, there are multiple ways in which you can save bandwidth. One of the most important solutions would be to cache the images on the user's device. You didn't tag your question with a particular programming language, but if by chance you're using Android, you can use Glide library for Android, or Coil if you're using Jetpack Compose.
Another option would be to display a small preview of the original images. This means that you should also add the preview of that image to the Firebase Storage too. This kind of image is called the thumbnail of the image. You can create the thumbnail yourself in code, or you can use:

Resize Images Extension from Firebase


Use this extension to create resized versions of an image uploaded to a Cloud Storage bucket.

So using this Extension, the hard work is done for you behind the scenes. So you'll be able to get only the thumbnail that will have the size of only a few KB. However, if you need the original image, then you can access it on demand. In that way, you can have faster downloads and lower bills to pay.
